# How can I increase the size of my integer variable in PHP?

Tags: php

I need to store a huge number in a PHP variable (it's for a programming contest if you're wondering why). However, if the number is too big, it gets displayed as `6.2995416979471E+77`. Is there a way to store that huge number in PHP?

Comment: "Display" and "store" are two different things. You're successfully storing 6.2995416979471E+77 (which is a very sizeable number) and displaying it. Are you expecting it to be displayed differently? Are you trying to store an integer or is there a fractional part?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`integers` have a limited size of 32 or 64bit, depending on your architecture.
`floats` can store values of any size, but are imprecise.

If you want to work with giant, precise numbers, use strings and the [BC Math](http://php.net/bc) extension.

Comment: And fwiw: you can check your max int with: `echo PHP_INT_MAX;`

Answer (score 0):

```
$bigNumber = 1234567890; // etc
echo number_format($bigNumber, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried PHP's [BCMath](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php) arbitrary precision functions?  They use strings to represent numbers.